# Perform some operation on each of recursive structure's element, without adding methods to it in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, recurrence

**The task:** perform operation on each of recursive structure's element, without modifying it (the structure has only members and no methods except for constructor) inside `Presenter::present(...)` method (that makes use of private members of `Presenter`).

**The problem:** the structure does NOT have any methods except for constructor.

**Example:**

I have an structure:

```
struct Component{
    std::vector<Component *> children;
    Component * parent;
    std::string ID;
    std::string content;
    Component(ID, content){...}
};
```

Then I have some code like:

```
Component * a, * b, * c1, * c2;
a = new Component("A", "a content");
b = new Component("B", "b content");
c1 = new Component("C1", "c1 content");
c2 = new Component("C2", "c2 content");
b->parent = a;
a->children.push_back(b);
c1->parent = b;
c2->parent = b;
b->children.push_back(c1);
b->children.push_back(c2);
```

I now want, having `a` pointer passed to my `Presenter::present(...)`:

```
class Presenter{
private:
    std::string somethingImportant; // = "sth";
    ...
public:
    std::string present(Component * a){
        ... //on each component's children (and component itself):
            //get ID and content then add something from this (Presenter)
            //or modify the ID/content a bit.
            //At the end, return the result (for all components together).
    }
    ...
}
```

Output to `std::string` (or console, nvm) all `ID`-`content` pairs like:

```
A a content sth
B b content sth
C1 c1 content sth
C2 c2 content sth
```

It could be easily achieved by adding some `recursivePresent(std::string &output)` method to `Component` structure.

But I want to know if **it's possible to do it without modifying `Component` structure** (without adding any method to it)?

**EDIT** (made because of comments): Note that the output makes use of some `Presenter`'s private/protected members/methods - I cannot assume that it will be just one "sth" like in an example.

I cannot find such solution, but I believe that somebody here can surprise me with some crazy idea ;)

Comment: Hint: a member `recursivePresent(std::string &output)` is essentially the same as a nonmember `recursivePresent(const Component &c, std::string &output)` assuming that all the data members required are accessible.

Comment: Then do it, just make a recursivePresent which is not inside Component but takes one

Comment: Ok, but it has to be called inside the `Presenter::present(...)` and have access to other `Presenter`'s members/methods. I've made an edit to original question, sorry for not being precise from start.

Comment: Why not having it (the recursivePresent helper) on Presenter?

Comment: @firda can you explain it a bit? I'm not sure what do you mean.

Comment: You could do it with a recursive lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to comment: @firda can you explain it a bit? I'm not sure what do you mean.**
**My comment was: Why not having it (the recursivePresent helper) on Presenter?**

```
class Presenter {
    void presentRecursive(Component *c, std::ostream& out) {
        out << c->ID << ' ' << c->content << std::endl;
        for(auto p : c->children) presentRecursive(p, out);
    }
public:
    void present(Component *c) {
        presentRecursive(c, std::cout);
    }
};
```

Comment: Now when I see it, it looks so clear/obvious. Thank you very much :) That's exactly what I wanted to achieve. Somehow, I could not think of it (I feel silly now). Once more, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, a C++ `struct` (or `class`) object does not know its structure, fields, layout or size. These are only known at compilation time.

If you add a new field `long newfield;` at the end of your `struct Component`, most routines in your code will stay the same (except those allocating such a structure, they are using its size).

You need to have some runtime meta-data describing the structure of your object.